# how to change summary property information set of a file using powershell

Tags: powershell

If I have any file and I want to chage the summary property infromation set of that file how can I do that , I am mainly concerned for this attributes "Title , Subject , Category , Keywords, Comments , Source , Author , Revision No."

""[image]

Answer (score 3):

how about this one:

```
 # Load SharePoint library
 [system.reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Sharepoint")

 # Connect to the site collection http://SP2010 and store the object in the $site variable
 $site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://SP2010")

 # Connect to the root site in the site collection and store the object in $root
 $root = $site.rootweb

 # Store the Shared Documents document library in a variable $Docs
 $docs = $root.lists["Shared Documents"]

 # Display all the documents, their titles, names and IDs
 $docs.items | format-table -property title,name,id

 # Updates the title for each item in the list with Name
 $docs.items | ForEach { $_["Title"] = $_["Name"]; $_.Update() }

 # Display all the documents, their titles, names and IDs
 $docs.items | format-table -property title,name,id
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/04/06/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-add-custom-properties-to-a-microsoft-word-document.aspx

Comment: Hi can anyone please help to get the answer please

Answer (score 1):

@[Janki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/758663/janki):

try to take a look at this one - [File Property Edit Pro](http://www.foryoursoft.com/fpedit/index.htm)